# Convert excel file to jpg in c#

Tags: c#, excel, converters, spire

I am trying to use Spire dll to convert excel file to jpg .

so i have a xlsm file like this :

[image]

i use this code to convert it to jpg :

```
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\a.xlsm");
    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
    sheet.SaveToImage("exceltoimage.jpg");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("exceltoimage.jpg");
```

but the output is like this some of the cell can't be converted why i mean (#name)?

[image]

I have this warning in my page :

[image]

Comment: What is the content (formula) of the cells producing the `#name` error?

Comment: @Stewart_R The first row has a formula like this :=IF(I5>0,(F5/$N$2)*I5,0)

Comment: Is there anything sensitive in that file or would you be able to post it (or a trimmed down version) somewhere?

Comment: @Stewart_R I added some details ,could you please take a look

Comment: Can you post a copy of the file (or another one that gives the same problem) somewhere?

Comment: @Stewart_R how can i send this file ?could you please give me your mail ?

Comment: I uploaded the file :http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1430715984

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76847/discussion-between-ehsan-akbar-and-stewart-r).

Comment: @Stewart_R 
I uploaded the file :uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1430715984

Comment: http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/spire-xls-can-t-convert-excel-file-to-jpg-properly-t5335.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally use Aspose :

http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/category1129.aspx

example :

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Converting+Worksheet+to+Image

my sample code :

```
 Workbook workbook = new Workbook(@"D:\a.xlsm");
            //Get the first worksheet.
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[12];

            //Define ImageOrPrintOptions
            ImageOrPrintOptions imgOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
            //Specify the image format
            imgOptions.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            //Only one page for the whole sheet would be rendered
            imgOptions.OnePagePerSheet = true;

            //Render the sheet with respect to specified image/print options
            SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(sheet, imgOptions);
            //Render the image for the sheet
            Bitmap bitmap = sr.ToImage(0);

            //Save the image file specifying its image format.
            bitmap.Save(@"d:\SheetImage.jpg");
```

It works great for me .

Comment: Can you share me Aspose.dll? please!

Comment: @AIVN just in first link in my post download the first one Aspose.Cells for .NET 17.7 (DLLs only)